# Mutating a slice of an array doesn't work

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

```
import numpy as np
def solve_eps(eps):
    A = np.array([[eps, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1]])
    b = np.array([1 + eps, 1, 2])

    m_21 = A[1, 0] / A[0, 0]
    m_31 = A[2, 0] / A[0, 0]

    print("What A[1, :] should be:", A[1, :] - A[0, :] * m_21)
    A[1, :] = A[1, :] - A[0, :] * m_21
    print("But it won't assign it to the slice!!!!!", A[1, :])
```

If we run `solve_eps(2)`, you see that the slice doesn't assign:

> What A[1, :] should be: [ 0.  -0.5  0. ]
>   But it won't assign it to the slice!!!!! [0 0 0]

But, if you run:

```
A = np.array([[3, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2]])
A[1, :] = A[1, :] - (A[0, :] * 4)
```

> A[1, :] = [-10, -2, -2]

What's going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `dtype=float` when you define `A`:

```
A = np.array([[eps, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1]], dtype=float)
```

The reason you assignment failed was because you were assigning floats to an integer array.

Assigning integers to an integer slice works fine, as you noticed.

Comment: Thanks, you're a lifesaver. I've been using numpy for years and have never encountered this issue! Probably because I typically make them floats regardless.

Comment: I have to wait a few minutes, but I will when the option is available!